# How to use the SDK Firebase (Android) in Nativescript

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to use the sdk Firebase natively on Android but when I try to initialize Firebase using:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
```

I receive this error

> System.err: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process *******. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

in my **app.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
}
```

can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, thank you so much for your reply @attdona :)

I solved by doing more or less what you did.

The only differences are that:

1. To use a dynamic **build.gralde** I created a **hook** to replace the
   original one with mine to compile.
2. Always using a **hook** I copied
   the file **google-services.json** from **App_Resources/Android/** to
   **platforms/android/app**

Answer (score 0):

Add rules to `platforms/android/build.gradle` file, to include the google-services plugin and the Google's Maven repository:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Insert firebase dependencies to `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
  //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
  //compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
  // ...
}
```

And at the end of `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` insert:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Finally, if you hit the error:

```
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

Copy manually the `google-services.json`file:

```
cp app/App_Resources/Android/google-services.json platforms/android/app/google-services.json
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I have this error:

> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Comment: the fact is that I do not want to add the dependency in platofroms / android / build.gradle but I would like to use only the app.gradle file in order to use firebase. it's possible? I read the guide :)

Comment: I dont know if it is possible, personally I ended to save the  platforms/android/build.gradle as build.gradle.template outside the platforms dir and reinstalling again when necessary.

Comment: so there is not something dynamic?

Comment: Have you considered [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase)?

Comment: yes but I would like to natively use firebase on nativescript for android

Comment: I have found a solution that avoid to edit build.gradle. See the updated answer (remember to delete `apply plugin  ... google-services` from app.gradle)

Comment: is it automatic?

Comment: thanks so much for everything.
I did everything as you told me but it does not work, I think that file is not included anywhere.

Comment: I used a hook to replace the build.gradle at the time of compilation, what do you think?

Comment: I think it is a nice solution!

Comment: But I can not understand why your solution does not work in my case.

Comment: Have you deleted `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services` from app.gradle?

Comment: yes and I created the file include.gradle in the App_Resources /Android/ folder

Comment: Do you find the file `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/google-services.json`?

Comment: yes I found it platforms/android/app/src/main/res/google-services.json

Comment: I have built again from scratch (rm -rf platforms) and it works. I have nativescript version 3.4.1 and tns-core-modules 3.4.0

Comment: are you sure then you can use the sdk of firebase?

Comment: Yes, but it is very strange that this setup works only for me, I will try to investigate further.

Comment: It was my setup: I confirm that the solution with `include.gradle` does not work! I reverted my answer to the original version and I added precisely what I did to get firebase working.
Clearly not the best solution but I'm not able to improve further the solution.